# Learning page load time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to write javascript code. It has one button and when clicked it its open a webpage which I choose. Now I want to learn when this  page ( which I call) load.

Do you have any idea?

I think I cant express myself. I call another webpage from my webpaga. And I wantto learn 
calling website loading time.

I hope I tell my problem clearly. Do you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear on what you're asking, but using Firebug for Firefox along with ySlow extensions will give you alot of information about page and js load times.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about timing the page load, you could try implementing a timer like this:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
open_webpage(); // Do whatever you want to do that requires timing
var timeTaken = startTime - new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to time the page load process in javascript, in which case there's [episodes](http://stevesouders.com/episodes/index.php). Or in the browser, you can use YSlow.

Or do you want confirmation of when a page has loaded, in which case you'll want to perform an ajax request after the page has loaded which is something like this in jquery. (javascript isn't my primary language)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.post('/loaded');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, the following will tell you when the ajax content has loaded:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajaxPage.html",
  complete: function({
    alert("The ajax content has loaded!");
  }
});
```